# My WebSQL-script doesnt save the entrys in database

Tags: javascript, sql, database

I wrote a program that creates a database, a table called "picture" and saves values into it. But it does not work, he saves no entrys in the database. The console of Google Chrome Browser doesnt show any errors to me. Do you have an idea?

```
    var db = openDatabase("mskindb", '1.0', 'mskindb', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
var textMessage = "";

function initDatabase() {
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS picture (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, docid0 TEXT, docid1 TEXT, doctype TEXT, data TEXT, date TEXT' + 
            'creation_date TEXT, delete_date TEXT, transmit_date TEXT)');
        alert("initDatabase");
    });
}

function dropTables() {
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE patient');
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE picture');
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE senderMessage');
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE receiverMessage');
        initDatabase();
        alert("dropTables");
    });
}

function dropPicture() {
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE picture');
        initDatabase();
    });
}

function addPatient(patient) {
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO patient (lastname, firstname) VALUES (?, ?)', [patient.lastName, patient.firstName]);
    });
}

function addPicture() {
    //textMessage = document.getElementById("patientMessage").value;
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO picture (docid0, ' + 
            'docid1, doctype, data, date, creation_date, transmit_date, delete_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
            ["0", "0", "mSkinPicture", JSON.stringify(actualPhoto), new Date(), "0", "0", "0"]);
        alert("addPicture() ausgeführt");
        alert(JSON.stringify(actualPhoto))
    });
}

function displayAllPictures() {
    alert("1");
    var psrDisplayArea = document.getElementById("psrDisplayArea");
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        alert("2");
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM picture', [], function (tx, results) {
            alert("3");
            alert(results.rows.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                alert("4");
                alert(JSON.parse(results.rows.item(i).data));
            }
        }, null);
    });
}

//

actualPhoto = new photoData("HelloWorld");

function photoData(path) {
    this.path = path;
}

//

initDatabase();
addPicture();
displayAllPictures();
```

Answer (score 0):

transaction method provides you a callback function with an error object try to debug by this way:

```
function addPicture() {
  db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO picture (docid0, ' + 
        'docid1, doctype, data, date, creation_date, transmit_date, delete_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
        ["0", "0", "mSkinPicture", JSON.stringify(actualPhoto), new Date(), "0", "0", "0"]);
    alert("addPicture() ausgeführt");
    alert(JSON.stringify(actualPhoto))
}, function (error) {
    // Here check what your console says ^^
    console.log(error);
});
```

}

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/cordova/storage/storage.html#websql

Get in touch ;)

Comment: Thank you! My error: I don't set a "," after "date" in "initDatabase()"